# Why does syntax error appear after running code?

Tags: pascal

presently learning how to code in pascal and vba. Assisting my daughter who is preparing for examinations next year.  I am stuck on a problem concerning her present assignment.  After running the code the following errors were received:

main.pas(1,2) Fatal: Syntax error, "BEGIN" expected but "identifier N" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted

Tried fixing the code, but as i said I have just started learning to code.

```
   n: integer; (*n is ID number for each candidate*)
   DV: integer; (*DV is the number of district votes available*)
   VR: integer; (*VR is the number of votes received by the candidate in 
                the district*)
   x: integer;
   y: integer;
   Divide: integer;
   found: Boolean;
          n: array[1..10] of integer; (*n is an array of 10 integers*)
          Names: array[1…10] of string = (‘Richards’, ‘Gumbs’, ‘Carty’, 
            ‘Fleming’, ‘Jones’,  ‘Amorowat’, ‘De la cruz’, ‘Walker’, 
            ‘Brooks’, ‘Baker’);
   DV: array[1…10] of integer = (‘200’, ‘900’, ‘700’, ‘100’, ‘80’,  ‘15’, 
                                ‘6, ‘20’, ‘50’, ‘1’); 
   VR: array[1…10] of integer = (‘50’, ‘700’, ‘600’, ‘20’, ‘30’,  ‘2’, 
                                ‘6, ‘3’, ‘30’, ‘2’); 
   For x := 1 to 10 do 
   Begin
       Repeat
          Found:=false;
                writeln('Enter Candidate ID Number: ’);
                 readln(n);
     For y:= 1 to 10 do 
       if n = n[y] then
       Found = true; 
                writeln(‘Name of Candidate is’ Names: array[1] ‘.’);
                readln;
                writeln(‘Number of votes available in the District is’ 
                        DV: array[1] ‘.’);
                readln;
                writeln(‘Number of votes received by the Candidate in the 
                        District is’ VR: array[1] ‘.’);
                readln;
            Endif;
      For y:= 1 to 10 do 
           if n = n[y] then
           Divide:= (DV: array[1] DIV VR: array[1]);
           Result:= Divide;
               writeln(‘The percentage of votes received by’ Names: 
                       array[1] ‘is’ Result ‘.’);
               readln;
            if Result:>= 0.20 then
               writeln(‘The candidate,’ Names: array[1] ‘is to receive a 
               refund.’);
                readln;
            Elseif
               writeln(‘The candidate,’ Names: array[1] ‘will not receive 
               a refund.’);
                readln;
            Endif;
    Endif;
```

End;

The expected result is to choose a candidate by his ID number which would lead to his name, the number of vote available in a district and the number of votes the candidate obtained being displayed.  it would then result in a calculation between the two vote counts (division) and if the percentage is greater than 20% he would receive a refund, if less than 20% he would not receive a refund.  either result should be displayed.

Comment: Which pascal compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you missing the "var" for the variable section, or is it just after that you copied?

Comment: Anyway, you need a book, course, tutorial etc.. Trying to use online resources as syntax checker will not be efficient.

Comment: Btw, see if inserting `var` on a line above `n : integer ...` avoids the problem.

Comment: I am using an online compiler,

Comment: the var was missing from the top of the code.

Comment: the new errors are   main.pas(18,15) Fatal: illegal character "'�'" ($E2)
Fatal: Compilation aborted

Comment: .. additionally SO is not the online syntax corrector for the online compiler...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you q, as it currently stands, isn't really suited to SO
because SO is really about specific (single) programming problems, not
incrementally debugging source code (see Sertac's comment), nor providing
online tutorials, which I think you probably need at this point.  And I feel
rather uncomfortable about posting this as an answer, because it isn't one
in the normal SO sense.  However it seems to me that you could use a few pointers:

1. Unless you **absolutely** have to use the online compiler, download
   and use a free online one like Free Pascal, which is well supported, uses
   standard Pascal syntax, and I'm sure there are basic first-time tutorials
   available.  See [here](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloads) to download Lazarus, which is an excellent IDE for Free Pascal (which is included
   in the install) and [here](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Tutorial) for an introductory tutorial.
2. Secondly, there are structural and syntactic elements of your source-code
   which are definitely **not** standard Pascal, in particular `endif` and `elseif`.
   Another example is that in standard Pascal, you have to surround a string (like your
   Richards, etc) with single-quotes `'`, not precede the string by a back-quote.  This is very possibly the cause of your "illegal character" error
3. For a decent Free Pascal introductory
   tutorial see [here](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Object_Pascal_Introduction) and this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VPvQ_dXMhw), both found by googling

   "free pascal" introductory tutorial.
4. Fourthly, your online compiler ought to be complaining about the `endif` abd `elseif`s, the incorrectly string formatting and the fact that several of your variables are duplicated (`DV` and `VR` used as the names of an integer variable and an array, for example as in Pascal, identifiers within the same 'scope' need to have unique names (the fact that I should explain what 'scope' means is a sign that what the q needs is a tutorial).